# Qt QGraphicsView not playing any video

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qmediaplayer

I have a very simple QT 5.11.0 application with a graphicsview that i would like to play a video in.

Here is my code, it compiles, loads and displays a blank graphicsview.

```
#include "Demo_TeleLink.h"


Demo_TeleLink::Demo_TeleLink(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    player = new QMediaPlayer();
    videoItem = new QGraphicsVideoItem;
    newString = "C://Users//Chris//Desktop//Sample1.mp4";

    ui.graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    player->setVideoOutput(videoItem);

    ui.graphicsView->scene()->addItem(videoItem);

    player->setMedia(QUrl(newString));

    ui.graphicsView->fitInView(videoItem);

    player->play();
}
```

All the required objects are declared in the header as points if needed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QUrl("/path/of/video")` is not a valid url since the scheme file that indicates that it is a local file is not deduced, there are 2 possible solutions to this:

```cpp
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(newString));
```

or

```cpp
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromUserInput(newString));
```

Maybe the path is not encoded correctly, try using the following code and selecting the video manually

```
newString = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                         tr("Open Video"),
                                         QDir::homePath(),
                                         tr("Video Files (*.mp4)"));
```

The OP indicates that it obtains the following error message:

```
DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040266 (IDispatch error #102)
```

And according to the [QTBUG-52082](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52082) reported, the solution is to install the codecs to play mp4 from http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, sadly still a blank window no matter which option i use there.

Comment: @Chris Do you get an error message in the "Application Output" tab of Qt Creator?

Comment: This is running in VS

Comment: @Chris I do not work with VS, maybe there is a tab similar to that information, if not, then open a cmd and run the .exe from there and you will surely get an error message.

Comment: I swapped the subsystem over to console so i can print debugs, and there is an error code. 

DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040266 (IDispatch error #102)

Comment: Both messages only appear at the line player->play();

Comment: @Chris Try what I indicated in my update, install K-lite

Comment: Still the same, thou memory usage went up 20mb while running.

Comment: @Chris mmm, I don't understand you, have you installed the codecs I indicated? The problem is not Qt but Directshow that does not have the codec installed to play mp4

Comment: Awesome, you nailed the issue thank you very much!

Its playing now!